# Sonarqube runner exits with exit code 138 in TeamCity run

Tags: teamcity

I'm migrating current stack to Teamcity and sonarqube build step suddenly fails with following output:

```
[09:56:54][Step 2/3] 09:56:54.862 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
[09:56:54][Step 2/3] 09:56:54.872 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: hg
<analysis>
[09:58:28][Step 2/3] 09:58:28.921 INFO  - 1197/1831 files analyzed
[09:58:28][Step 2/3] 09:58:28.921 WARN  - Missing blame information for the following files:
[09:58:28][Step 2/3] 09:58:28.921 WARN  -   * <list of paths>
...
[09:58:29][Step 2/3] 09:58:29.024 WARN  - This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] Total time: 3:27.871s
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] Final Memory: 18M/161M
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] ERROR: Caused by: -1
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] ERROR: 
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] Process exited with code 1
[09:58:30][Step 2/3] Step SonarQube Runner failed
```

How do i beat up that problem so the build would continue, or, at least, get the exact reason build fails? Mercurial data directory (.hg) should be in place, checkout is done on agent side.

Comment: i was able to suppress the error by disabling scm sensor in Sonarqube, but that's something like putting a stone in your technical debt shoe.

Comment: Did you try doing what it suggested?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, i'm not familiar with runner, don't know even where it is located in the teamcity structure and how can i reproduce the very same environment.

Comment: What I'm really confused about is: Why do you believe this is an ops issue?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i'm always confused where my questions like that should be placed - serverfault, superuser, or so - but i thought this was the closest of three (correct me if i'm wrong, feel free to migrate question elsewhere if you think that is right)